# Detect all images are completely loaded when using browser-level lazy-loading

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Is that possible to detect all images on a page are completely loaded when using browser-level lazy-loading (i.e. loading="lazy")?

Thanks.

Comment: `onload` doesn't work?

Comment: @boxdox yes, `onload` doesn't work. This event is triggered immediately when the page content (not including the images) is loaded.